# Electron app with pm2 packaged for Mac respawns itself

Tags: macos, electron, pm2

I made an Electron app that uses the node.js package pm2, a process manager. It all works as expected until the application is packaged using electron-packager. Then, each instance of the application starts a new instance. If I remove the `pm2.connect()` instruction, everything works as expected again. What's going on?

Can pm2 not be used in packaged applications on OS X?

Comment: It can be used in packaged electron application but since you did not provide any example code for this it's hard to pinpoint where things went wrong.